# How can I predict that how many flights will be there?

Tags: prediction

I have a dataset that contains (date of request , date of flight, from, to and price), now I want to get (date , from, to) and then predict the number of flights with these features by machine learning and data mining techniques.
what's your idea for predictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with linear and logistic regression which won't take into account the time series nature of your data. For that, start with Autoregression, (AR)Moving Average (MA) and Autoregressive Moving Average (ARMA) and go from there.

Here are some useful links to get you started:

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/09/common-machine-learning-algorithms/

https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-methods-in-python-cheat-sheet/